# error failed to execute git clone running composer commands (https://github.com/weatherapicom/php.git)

Tags: php, github, composer-php, putty

I'm trying to get started using weatherapi.com, section getting started [here](https://www.weatherapi.com/docs/).

SDK can be found through [here](https://github.com/weatherapicom/), choosing the PHP version [here](https://github.com/weatherapicom/php).

I want to run a script to retrieve the value for attribute 'cloud' in the 'current' object that the api can provide. The script will run on a hosted webserver (hostinger).

I get stuck now on trying to install that SDK, when running the command

```
composer install
```

in putty.

In putty I get following error message:

> *[RuntimeException]
> Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'https://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:*
> **@github.com//.git.git' '/home/u888702977/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com--.git/
> '
> Cloning into bare repository '/home/u888702977/.cache/composer/vcs/https---github.com--.
> git'...
> remote: Repository not found.
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com//.git.git/' not found*

File composer.json looks like this to start with:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com//.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "/": "*@dev"
  }
}
```

Composer is preinstalled on hostinger, version 1.10.21.
PHP version installed on hostinger is 5.5.38.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you want to `require` an `install` is used when you move the app and you want all the things you have previously `required` to be installed on the new location

Comment: `"url": "https://github.com//.git"` doesn't look right. You shouldn't need that `repositories` block at all here.

Comment: PHP 5.5.38 - really? That is horribly outdated